# Automatically create folder within multiple document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a client who has all their client folders in sharepoint online, they usually every year go ahead and manually create a new folder within each client folder with the year (2021).

They have asked if there is a way to automatically create a folder within each separate client folder rather than doing it manually

Help?!

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint online, we suggest you consider using Microsoft flow to automatically create a folder in document library.

In addition, remember to choose the appropriate trigger to start the flow.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers#create-new-folder